# first shown as blank then auto populate values when data is entered

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet for data entry. I have some columns that are populated automatically when other cells/columns are entered by user. So, some formula are entered in there.

Goal is to have these columns shown as blank before any data is entered, but populate values based on the formula in there. Also,
I don't know exactly how many rows may be entered by user, but roughly no more than 500.

As for now, I use `IF(ISBLANK(A1)," ", IF(....))` the formula  is in the second `IF(...)`, and auto fill till the 500th row. It apears to be working as I want ...But I am not sure how reliable this trick is.

Update:

Per some comments, I tried converting the sheet to a table (by ctrl + T) and specified the range to be down to 1000th row.

See before and after screen shot

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHgsp.png)
 column agegroup is a calculated field based on age. See the formula entered.

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWZik.png)
column agegroup at the 523th row (one after where auto filled I previously dragged down to) is not automatically populated.

Comment: If it appears to be working, then hard to say if there's a problem. In any case the formula you provide seemsOK

Comment: If you convert existing rows to a table (click inside used area and press ctrl+T), data being added to the next unused row automatically is placed inside the table and any formulas will populate down on their own.

Comment: I think you need a Table to help you, but if you can provide a more detail sample about this problem, it will more help.

Comment: @AlexM I converted the sheet to a table ranging till row 1000. I originally filled the formula up to 522th row. The 523th row didn't have the formula populate down...see my edited post. Thanks.